# How to use CSS sprites with textbox?

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I'm trying to use CSS sprites in a text box.
The image dimensions are 200x50 pixels and i want to display only part of the image lets say from (25px,25px)(x,y cordinates) with height 30px and width 50px.

```
.img_textbox
{
  background-image: url(images/ff.jpg);
  background-position: 25px 25px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

The above co-ordinates are decided by a third value, hence it varies according to the text in the textbox.

```
<input type="textbox" name="type" class="img_textbox" value="">
```

i tried using background-position and background-image properties, but didnt worked in my case.

How can i do it? What properties or tags should i use to make it work? please guide me...

thanks in advance..

Comment: You have it pretty much correct (though you'll want to add background-repeat: no-repeat). What part isn't working for you?

Comment: Works here also, in which browser you tested? FF5 and Chrome 12 works ok.

Comment: above code is changing textbox height to 30px and width to 50px. I want to show image of above size in textbox and which is at co-ordinate 25px,25px in `images/ff.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's at all a valid `<input type="textbox">`, you'd be better off using `<textarea>`.

css:

```
textarea.img_textbox {
  background-image: url(images/ff.jpg);
  background-position: 25px 25px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

html:

```
<textarea class="img_textbox" cols="5" rows="3">
  // value
</textarea>
```

Comment: -1 Sorry, doesn't work. This limts the size of the textarea element itself instead of only the size of the background image.

Comment: There's no notion of the container size in the question. Properly asked question is 50% of the right answer. You cannot limit the size of the background other than creating a container with specific size.

Comment: You'd think that it'd be assume not to have the image change the container though.. sorry if this comment is two years too late..

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a  with the background class applied on it and the  with transparent background and no borders inside?

css:

```
.img_textbox_back
{
  background-image: url(images/ff.jpg);
  background-position: 25px 25px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
}

.img_textbox
{
   background-color:transparent;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="img_textbox_back">
    <input class="img_textbox" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/X2kJ6/5/)?

HTML:

```
<span></span><input type="text" />
```

CSS:

```
span {
    background: url('images/ff.jpg') no-repeat 25px 25px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 75px;
    height: 55px;
    z-index: -1;
}
input {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Note that the text box is **not** inside the span to assure that the normal flow includes the (size of the) text box.

Of course you have to give height to the text box to show the image. Or you could use a textarea element.

Answer (score -1):

You don't see the image at all or something else?

In my sprite, I use position like this:

```
   .sprt {background-image:url("<path>");background-repeat:no-repeat;}   
   .arrow{
      background-position:-25px -25px;
      width:50px;height:30px;
    }
```

Then I use `<span class="sprt arrow"></span>` to show an arrow

Note the '-' before this coordinates.

Do you mind trying this?

```
textarea.img_textbox {
  background-image: url("images/ff.jpg");
  background-position: -25px -25px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
}
```